# Win10 Folder name changes still shows original name in other programs

Tags: windows-10

I have a very strange and annoying issue that when I change the name of a folder, it'll show the new folder name but when I copy it's path or open it in another program, it still shows the original name on that program. It doesn't happen to all my folders but only in some. I'm on Windows 10 Pro.

The screenshot shows the folder renamed into "New Soundx" and then having it's path copied into Notepad. The copied path in Notepad will still show its original name instead of the current.

[image]

Comment: Is that folder or parent folders currently being used by other software that might be actively utilizing that location (i.e. vocaloid itself)? Try closing vocaloid in taskmanager and all other processes related to it and see if you can alter the path (or better yet try it in safe mode)

Comment: I don't have anything running that would be using those folders. I tried safe mode as you suggested but same results. How can this be possible?? It's really annoying.

Comment: In control panel > file explorer options, if you enable "Show hidden files" and uncheck "Hide protected operating system files" then go back to the folder and refresh, is there a desktop.ini file in there? Check this link out, similar problem, but he ended up adding a registry value to fix his problem https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1824783-folders-not-staying-renamed

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me. After revealing all the hidden items I simply deleted all of them from my main folder. But now how can I prevent anymore hidden files from being created?

Comment: Can you create the dword: "UseDesktopIniCache" in: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer then set it to 0. Delete the problem desktop.ini and reboot. Or conversely if you don't want to fiddle with the registry, delete the problem desktop.ini, then (quickly so it doesn't get recreated): open notepad, leave it blank, go to Save As, change the "Save as type" drop-down from .txt to All Files, and set the name as desktop.ini and save it in the directory in question. That should prevent the "problem" desktop.ini from getting saved in that folder in future

Comment: Thank you so much JJ! You are really helpful.